# Equivalent of layer.redraw(true) in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers

I have a geojson layer in my OL3 app which I want to redraw every 5 seconds (to show movement on map) .

How do I do it ? Couldn't find the equivalent of Layer.redraw().

Comment: Have you looked at ol.animation? In general, vector drawing is smoother and handled differently in ol3, but it isn't entirely clear from your question what you are wanting to do.

Comment: @JohnBarça - My GeoJson data comes from postgres which is being updated every 5 seconds with new GPS data. I want to redraw the layer to show each time the current position of the units on the map (it keep changing...)

Comment: So, you are requesting data every 5 seconds using a recursive setTimeout call (or something similar) and you just want to know how to force the vector features to refresh?

Comment: @JohnBarça - If there is a better way I'm willing to learn ,but this is what I do , I want to show location of GPS in real time on map. GPS send their location to PostGIS and from there I read the data using GeoJSON (or I can use GeoServer) but I wish for the layer to update itself every once in a while.

Comment: Sure, I get what you are trying to do. Any chance of a code sample, because in my experience, if you put an animation loop in settimeout, with an ajax call to a remote server, and load the json that comes back using Format.GeoJSON or similar, the features will get updated.

Comment: @JohnBarça - Didn't write code yet , Was planning to. So what you suggest is re-adding the features every second ? no auto layer redraw ?

Comment: Clear the features from the vector layer and re-add them, within the callback handling the ajax call (I assume you will use ajax to get the json). This should work fine.

Comment: Will try it. in OL2 I didn't have to do it because layer.redraw did the ajax call itself .

Comment: Really. Sorry, I am being a bit thick today, but in which OL class, Layer.Vector? I'm looking at the source code and I don't see any mechanism whereby layer.redraw goes an ajax call?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how you can refresh a vector source every 5 seconds, from a web service returning features in a GeoJSON document:

```js
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();
var geojsonFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON();

window.setTimeout(function() {
  $.ajax('http://example.com/data.json', function(data) {
    var features = geojsonFormat.readFeatures(data
        {featureProjection:"EPSG:3857"});
    geojsonSource.clear();
    geojsonSource.addFeatures(features);
  });
}, 5000);
```

jQuery is used here for requesting the data through Ajax (`$.ajax`), but you can obviously use the library of your choice.

This code snippet also assumes that the map's projections is "EPSG:3857" (web mercator) and that the coordinates in the GeoJSON documents are longitudes and latitudes.

Comment: This code confuses me, should `vectorSource` and `geojsonSource` be merged?

Comment: I think you mean window.setInterval not setTimeout; otherwise it only does it once.

Answer (score 9):

I know that this question is old but i've finally found a solution to refresh a layer on openlayers 3.

You have to update params of the layer source like this:

```
var source = yourLayer.getSource();
var params = source.getParams();
params.t = new Date().getMilliseconds();
source.updateParams(params);
```

Comment: It seems not all sources support the `updateParams` method; OL3.18.2  only shows it for `ImageArcGISRest`, `ImageMapGuide`, `ImageWMS`, `TileArcGISRest` and `TileWMS`, and not for, e.g., `ol.source.Vector`.

Comment: [Date#getTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) may be better than [Date#getMilliseconds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMilliseconds) to  invalidate cache and force the layer to redraw as it will ensure a unique number each time.

Answer (score 5):

You can refresh a WFS layer with `myLayer.getSource().clear()`.

Comment: This did it for me with OpenLayers 3 v. 0.14.2 and a WFS GeoJSON vector source.

Comment: nothing wrong with a one-line answer if they are on the money. there should be a reputation award to have this info box removed.

Comment: The answer is correct, but this might show some flickering: upon calling `clear()` any existing features will be removed from the map right away, and only be added again after receiving the HTTP response. This is true for both specifying a value for `VectorOptions#url` and for `VectorOptions#loader`. For realtime data, manually doing some WebSockets or XHR magic and then calling `getSource().clear()` followed by `getSource().addFeatures(...)` might look better to the end user.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [changed](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Layer-Layer.html#changed) method for layers to indicate a change and let OL repaint it:

```
layer.changed();
```

Comment: You need to explain a bit more about how `layer.changed();` works perfect(ly) for layers.  The documentation description `Increases the revision counter and dispatches a 'change' event.` isn't really helpful.   How does using the changed() method answer the question regarding redrawing the map every 5 seconds?

Comment: I have used Ajax to save a revised geojson source, and the problem I had was that if I closed the layer and re-opened it the map used the cached (unrevised) version of the source. Once I cleared the cache the layer used the revised source as I would expect.  Unfortunately, the suggested `layer.changed();` had no effect for me, but `source.changed();` did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

With OL2 I used a layer refresh strategy which hasn't been added to OL3. Below is a self calling function that will use an ajax request to fetch the GeoJSON and then read it and add it to a source.

```
var yourSource = new ol.source.GeoJSON();

//add this source to a layer, the layer to a map with a view etc
...

//now fetch the data
var fetchData = function () {
    jQuery.ajax(url,
    {
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            yourSource.clear(); //remove existing features
            yourSource.addFeatures(yourSource.readFeatures(data));
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });

    //call this again in 5 seconds time
    updateTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        fetchData();
    }, 5000);
};
fetchData(); //must actually call the function!
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to refresh explicitly. 
Each time you update the content of a layer the map is refreshed requesting a new frame rendering.

To force rendering manually you have `map.render()` and `map.renderSync()`methods.

Comment: That doesn't update the content, just updates the map canvas itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if in OpenLayer 3 this works, but in actual version (OL6) I use a simple

```
layer.setStyle(layer.getStyle())
```